# Nondegenerate Conics

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having trouble seeing why the set of all nondegenerate conics is Zariski open in the parameter space $\mathbb{P}^5$.This is an exercise in Smith 5.2.2 that I am trying to do. I will be grateful to receive any help on this.

Comment: I guess a degenerate conic implies its parameters satisfying some polynomial equation (like vanishing of the resolvent). So their parameters together constitute a Zariski closed set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling the l.h.s. of the (homogeneous) conic equation 
$$A x^2 + 2 B x y + C y^2 + 2 D x z + 2 E y z + F z^2 = 0$$
preserves the locus, but other transformations of the l.h.s. do not, so we can regard
$$[A : B : C : D : E : F]$$
as homogeneous coordinates on the space of conics, which we identify with $\mathbb{P}^5$. A conic is degenerate iff the discriminant of this form, namely,
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} A & B & D \\ B & C & E \\ D & E & F\end{pmatrix} = ACF + 2 BDE - AE^2 - FB^2 - CD^2$$
is zero.

> In particular, the set of degenerate conics is a projective subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^5$, and hence is Zariski closed, and so its complement, the set of nondegenerate conics, is Zariski open.